# Angular 4: Does not execute Javascript code

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I am working with Angular 4 and I have problems installing a template that we buy in the company. It happens that I do not execute any Javascript code, exhaustively reviewing the possible problem, I noticed that there is a pending websocket, but I'm not using websockets, nor nodejs, I'm just using Angular in its basic configuration. The websocket call is made to the following address: ws://localhost:4200/sockjs-node/844/u0jdhdnu/websocket

Here an image:

[image]

As an additional fact, today I installed the new version of **@angular/cli** Could that be? I think Javascript gets stuck just because there is no answer.

Comment: The websocket is because of live-reaload (HMR) while in dev mode. The screenshot looks like it's executing javascript (at least it's rendering an angular application) but get's stuck somewhere. Are there no errors on the console? And what template is this about (and a template for what???)

Comment: It is a template that the company bought for an internal development. No, no console error is displayed. I tried running an alert ("Hello world"), but it did not show any alert, and I think that is precisely because of that problem. What should I do since I started the project?

Comment: If your company bought the template, contact the seller, he should give you better support than some programmers on stackoverflow tired of using their crystal balls

Comment: The support of the template does not include Angular 4, only AngularJS and Material Design. You do not believe me? You are not obliged to comment if you do not want to help, do not worry, I use all the possible mechanisms to solve my problem. Here is a small image of the control panel of themeforest: https://ibb.co/kreJdQ

Comment: With that little information, we are almost unable to help, for example u never stated in your answer that the theme is an AngularJs theme. And it's saying `Compatible With: AngularJS` not Angular. Maybe provide some more information about your setup.

Comment: The theme has 3 versions: pure HTML, AngularJS and Material Design. I chose pure HTML: https://ibb.co/ikKRyQ

Comment: The problem is that I do not have more information, I do not have errors in console I do not know what could be, before asking this question I looked for many possibilities. I think I'm going back to the previous version of @angular/cli

Comment: So you chose "pure HTML", did you implemented any angular component, or is the theme offering you to import the theme based component into your angular/cli project?

Comment: All the code I put inside the app.component.html (even the links to css and javascript). https://ibb.co/mgjyCk